# how do I access this class

Tags: java, android

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.net.Uri;

public class LoadSettings 
{
public static void LoadMySettings   (Context ctx)
{
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = ctx.getSharedPreferences("MY_SHARED_PREF", 0);
String strSavedMem1 = sharedPreferences.getString("gSendTo", "");
String strSavedMem2 = sharedPreferences.getString("gInsertInto", "");
String cCalId = sharedPreferences.getString("gCalID", "");

setInsertIntoStr(strSavedMem2);
setSendToStr(strSavedMem1);
}

private static String cSendToStr;
private static String cInsertIntoStr;
private int cCalId;
private Uri cCalendars;

public String getSendToStr()
{
    return this.cSendToStr;
}
public static void setSendToStr(String pSendToStr)
{
    cSendToStr = pSendToStr;
}
public String getInsertIntoStr()
{
return this.cInsertIntoStr;
}

public static void setInsertIntoStr(String pInsertIntoStr)
{
cInsertIntoStr = pInsertIntoStr;
}

}
```

from the calling class i have tryed lots the current is.

```
LoadSettings.LoadMySettings(this);
```

but when i try to get some data for example.

```
textSavedMem1.setText(LoadSettings.getSendToStr());
```

i get a Null error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`LoadMySettings` is not a class but a method (so it should start with a lower case, if you follow Oracle/Sun's naming conventions for the Java language).

You access it indeed by calling `LoadSettings.loadMySettings(someContext)`, where `someContext` is the context to pass around. In your example, we don't know what `this` refers to, so maybe your error lies there.

---

Then when you do this: `textSavedMem1.setText(LoadSettings.getSendToStr());`

You call a non-static method, so that should be either using an instance of `LoadSettings` or, more likely considering your code, you could change `getSendToStr` to be:

```
    public static String getSendToStr()
    {
        return cSendToStr;
    }
```

Though that seems to be rather bad design.

Maybe if you tell us more about what you try to do, we can help more, as as such our answers will just take you one step further.

---

**EDIT:** *Ok, I just figured out what you are trying to do...*

You need to go back and learn *basic Java concepts* and read on *access modifiers*, and *constructors* first, and OO semantics in Java in general.

Change your class to this:

```
public class LoadSettings 
{
    public LoadSettings(Context ctx)
    {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =
            ctx.getSharedPreferences("MY_SHARED_PREF", 0);
        String strSavedMem1 = sharedPreferences.getString("gSendTo", "");
        String strSavedMem2 = sharedPreferences.getString("gInsertInto", "");
        String cCalId = sharedPreferences.getString("gCalID", "");

        setInsertIntoStr(strSavedMem2);
        setSendToStr(strSavedMem1);
    }

    private String cSendToStr;
    private String cInsertIntoStr;
    private int cCalId;
    private Uri cCalendars;

    public String getSendToStr()
    {
       return cSendToStr;
    }

    public void setSendToStr(String pSendToStr)
    {
        cSendToStr = pSendToStr;
    }

    public String getInsertIntoStr()
    {
        return cInsertIntoStr;
    }

    public void setInsertIntoStr(String pInsertIntoStr)
    {
        cInsertIntoStr = pInsertIntoStr;
    }

}
```

And create a new instance of `LoadSettings` with:

```
LoadSettings mySettings = new LoadSettings(someContext);
```

You can then correctly invoke:

```
textSavedMem1.setText(mySettings.getSendToStr());
```

Comment: I THANK you very much for your response NO exceptions no buts. I have several books on Java and will try to find the area's your talking about and read some more. This is hard for me as being dyslectic reading is hard (strange hay cos i do programing). I find computers great as they just wait for you to get it write.

Comment: I have found info about "constructors" and now understand "why it is so" thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Haylem has the right of it, but I just wanted to add a comment:

There are basically two design patterns in Java for what you're trying  to do.  One is the static class where all the methods and variables are static and you access them as e.g.

```
LoadSettings.loadMySettings(this);
string = LoadSettings.getSendToStr()
// etc.
```

The other pattern is the "singleton" class where you create exactly one instance of the class and you access the instance:

```
LoadSettings ls = new LoadSettings(this);
ls.loadMySettings();
string = ls.getSendToStr();
```

Either way is good, but what you're doing is a mish-mash of both methods and it won't work.